# Is there a way to know the dimensions of a widget before laying it out on the screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a breadcrumb widget in my Flutter app and I would like to achieve the following behavior:

[image]

Let's say the red outlined area is the space I have for my breadcrumb and that each element of the breadcrumb has a different width. The breadcrumb should be responsive, i.e. it should show elements as long as there is enough space to show them, otherwise, remove some of the elements and add that '...' button in the middle. Clicking on that button shows an overlay that contains the removed elements.

Now, I want to know how much space each breadcrumb element will take ***before*** it is laid out on the screen. Only then, I can decide whether there is enough space for it to be shown in the breadcrumb or it should be part of the '...' button.

I tried to use [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) which gives you information about how much space a widget takes after laying it out. It also needs to layout each child once, which makes it unuseful in my use case.

P.S: Think about the breadcrumb used in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419078-stylemask). That's the same behavior I want to achieve.

Comment: use `CustomPaint` - it will be much more easier

Comment: @pskink I'm sorry but how is `CustomPaint` supposed to help me? Could you please explain your idea more?

Comment: This is only helpful if I want to render text widgets but what if I want to use buttons or icons for the breadcrumb elements?

Comment: so use `CustomMultiChildLayout` - why do you need to `layoutChild()` twice or more for one child?

Comment: I don't, it has to layout each child _exactly_ once. In my use case, I need to layout children until I run out of space and then stop, which is not possible using `CustomMultiChildLayout` because then some of the children are not laid out.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't.

You were already using `CustomMultiChildLayout`, that's good, it shows me that you should have some basic understanding of how flutter rendering pipeline works. Then it should be clear to you of the 3 steps: parent passes down constraints, child reports its size, parent decides where to place the child. So in short, again, you cannot get children's size before layout.

---

Now move on to the thing you want to achieve. I agree `CustomMultiChildLayout` cannot achieve what you want to do, but not for the reason you listed. The main problem is `CustomMultiChildLayout` forces you to layout each child once, *and then position them*. You *must* position each child, you cannot skip a child if you don't like it (too big), and you cannot fabricate new stuff that's not your children. If you could achieve these 2 things, then getting children's size *after* layout isn't going to be a problem.

To achieve those, the easiest way is to use `CustomPaint`, if everything you need to do, are text-based or just simple shapes. Use `TextPainter` to layout a text, get its size, then decide whether to paint that text, or paint "..." (skip a child and fabricate your own) instead. You can search on how to do these things easily, but mostly search on `TextPainter`.

If you want to paint other widgets as your children, and optionally skip some of them while fabricating others, you should write your own `RenderObject`. That is one level lower than "widgets-level". If you have never done that before, you can research on that topic as well.